# Azure App registration using user+app access vs app-only access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration

I am developing an azure web app service called emailservice, which is supposed to communicate to a mailbox created in office365 exchange online. Suppose the user account for the mailbox is x @y-domain.com.
The webapp is supposed to retrieve messages automatically form the inbox or send messages when an special events happen. I have decided to use Microsoft graph api for this matter. I need to do app registration.
I am not sure whether I should use user+app access or app-only access. I am not sure if both of accesses are possible, and it is just matter of choice which one to use.
I have seen code snippet where they suggest to have app only access + Mail.ReadWrite and Mail.Send permissions. Again, I am not sure it is just a matter of choice or user+app access can be used for this scenario as well.
I would appreciate if someone shed some light on this.

I have some Microsoft documents but not sure which one is suitable or whether both of them possible for the scenario I described.

Comment: User+App access allows your application to act on behalf of a signed-in user that uses Delegated permissions where user interaction is needed. With **Delegated** permissions, you can **only** read mails of signed-in user and shared mailbox.

Comment: App-only scenario lets the application act without a signed-in user using permissions of **Application** type that gives you access to read any user's mailbox in the tenant.

Comment: Thanks @Sridevi, it was crisp and clear!

Answer (score 0):

> `User+App` access allows your application to act on behalf of a signed-in user that uses **Delegated** permissions where user interaction is needed to acquire token.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted `Mail.Read` permission of **Delegated** type like this:

[image]

With  **Delegated**  permissions, you can  **only**  read mails of signed-in user(/me endpoint) and shared mailbox.

**User+App access in C# (Interactive flow):**

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "appId";

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages.GetAsync();
    foreach (var message in messages.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {message.Subject}");
    }
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> App-only scenario lets the application act without a signed-in user using permissions of **Application** type that gives you access to read any user's mailbox in the tenant.

For this, I registered one application and granted permissions of **Application** type as below:

[image]

With **Application** permissions, you can read mails of any user present in the tenant without any login to acquire token.

**App-only access in C# (Client credentials flow)**

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = "tenantID";
        var clientId = "appID";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var messages = await graphClient.Users["sri@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"].Messages.GetAsync();

            foreach (var message in messages.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {message.Subject}");
            }
        }
        catch (ServiceException serviceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(serviceException.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I developed code in js.I understand what you are saying. Here are my questions
In case of app only access: why do you need Mail.Read and Mail.ReadWrite? Isn’t Mail.ReadWrite covers Mail.Read as well?
My  code for app only access without human interaction and only Mail.Send and Mail.ReadWrite for app only permissions fails.
I used acquireTokenByClientCredential to get access token + usual fetch call with access token and the message. I then run it on my local machine. it complains about "...Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request"

Comment: If Mail.ReadWrite is given, there is no need to add Mail.Read as it'll included in it. Regarding the error, could you include endpoints screenshot of your app Overview page from Portal by editing your question to check whether you are using any cross cloud?

Comment: I fixed the issue and did not get a chance to mention it here. I was mixing commercial cloud and gov cloud. That is why it was complaining about cross cloud.